# Regular expressions based off model entry in Django?

Tags: regex, django

If I create a new user in my database modeled by the following:

If this question doesn't make sense, I'm more wondering where data exists in an example url like: `url(r'^members/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.single')`

what exactly is  and how can I create a field like that?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self,):
        return (self.user)
```

How could it be possible to have a regular expression URL mapped based on that user that lies within that model? Is it possible?
Or maybe even the phonenumber if I had a phone number field in there. Just curious, trying to better understand regex. Thanks!

I want something like

```
def single(request, username1):
    try:
        user = Address.objects.get(Address.user=username1)
        single_user = user
    except:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('single_user.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

To work with:
`url(r'^members/(?P<username1>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.single')`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions has nothing to do with model from the perspective of this question. Instead Django imports and calls view based on url mapping.

View deals with models. Check the docs on [How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

```
url(r'^members/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.single')
```

Here if request come to DOMAIN/members/username `profiles.views.single` view will be called.

Valid username format is `\w` . `\w` stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]

[username](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.usernamehttp://) is a field of [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#user) model which comes from django.contrib.auth.models

Check [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) and [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) as well.

#### update

To filter by username use

`Address.objects.filter(user__username=username1) #user is a Foreignkey`

For regular fields just

```
Address.objects.filter(field_to_filter=view_argument)
```

Comment: I've added an update to the end of my post of what I want to achieve. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm basically wondering how I can add a custom slug to the url based on a user_inputted parameter

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with the example code you give is how you perform the query: you don't use the class name inside the parentheses.

```
user = Address.objects.get(user=username1)
```

If you didn't have the catch-all except clause there, you would have received a SyntaxError which might have helped you debug this yourself: that's why it's a very very bad idea to have those. Only catch the `Address.DoesNotExist` exception, or even better just use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut.